# Definition of Submanifols

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

[image]

My doubt here is what condition $(ii)$ means in the definition. I am finding it difficult to understand that why does it says.

Comment: This defines the tangent space of $M$ and the dimension of $M$. All it says is that the tangent space of $M$ has dimension $m$ and so the dimension of $M$ is $m$

Comment: Think of a parametrized surface in $\Bbb R^3$ as an example.

Comment: What is the source of this definition? Note that (iii) says that $M$ has the subspace topology inherited from $S$. This property is not covered by requiring $M$ a **subset** of $S$; it could have a topology not related to $S$:

Comment: It is from "Method of information geometry by Shun-Ichi Amari"